# java apache IOUtils breaks file content

Tags: java, pdf, apache-commons

I need to encode/decode pdf file into Base64 format.
So I read file from disk into String(because I will receive file in String Base64 format in future);

```
String pdfString = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(new
            File("D:\\vrpStamped.pdf")));
byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(pdfString.getBytes());

byte[] newPdfArray = Base64.decodeBase64(encoded);
FileOutputStream imageOutFile = new FileOutputStream(
        "D:\\1.pdf");
imageOutFile.write(newPdfArray);
imageOutFile.close();
imageOutFile.flush();
```

So my `D:\\1.pdf` doesnt opens in AdobeReader, but if I read file straight to byte array,  using `IOUtils.toByteArray(..)` instead ,all works fine and my `D:\\1.pdf` file sucessfuly opens in Adobe Reader:

```
byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\vrpStamped.pdf"))););
```

It seems to me thath `IOUtils.toString(..)` change something inside file content. So how can I convert file to String with not content breaking?

Comment: Why do you put some random bytes (the pdf file) into a String and then expect the String to be a valid representation of your bytes? Don't. It isn't. Strings have encodings and are not simply 1:1 translatable to a byte array.

Comment: So, How I can encode pdf file into String Base64 and send it by using Rest service? I use String for that, its works fine with images, but not with pdf files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to encode a pdf...

```
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(new File("/home/fschaetz/test.pdf")));
byte[] encoded = Base64.encode(bytes);
String str = new String(encoded);
```

...now do something with this encoded String, for example, send it via a Rest service.

And now, if you receive an encoded String, you can decode and save it like this...

```
byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(str.getBytes());
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/fschaetz/result.pdf"));
output.write(decoded);
output.close();
```

Works perfectly fine with all files, not limited to images or pdfs.

What your example is doing is...

1. Read the pdf into a String (which pretty much destroys the data, since you are reading binary data into a String)
2. Encode this spring (which is in all likelyhood not a valid representation of the original pdf anymore)
3. Decode it and save it to disk